# Android Studio - ImageView no preview in .xml file

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView in my activity that is visible when I run the app.

But it is not visible in the preview in the Design view of the activity_main.xml. 
How do I make it show?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    ...

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It does not matter wether it is a .png that I put in drawables or a symbol I take from Android Studio.

Comment: Can you please show here your activity_main.xml file contents?

Comment: Try background instead of srccompat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompatActivity `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24"`

if you are using Activity `android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24"`